# LowercaseUrls = true in RouteOptions doesn't affect URLs with non-Roman characters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing

In ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
    services.AddMvc();
}

<a asp-action="New-Post">New post</a>
```

Works fine giving URL like http://domain/controller/new-post

But this one

```
<a asp-action="Новая-Публикация">Новая публикация</a>
```

produces URL like [http://domain/controller/Новая-Публикация](http://domain/controller/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

How to fix it to get URLs in low case only for any language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `RouteCollection` uses `ToLowerInvariant()` to lower-case the URL: https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/032bcf43b2cefe641fc6ee9ef3ab0769024a182c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteCollection.cs#L155

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a copy of this String object converted to lowercase using the casing rules of the invariant culture.

And from [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.

So it will not work with other alphabets.

You should check if there is an issue on this in the [Routing repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing), and post one there. They'll be able to tell if it would be feasible to implement.

Comment: Thank you, juunas, I've created the issue https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/435